# Implementing serializable and externalizable in the same class?

Tags: java, serialization, transient, externalizable

I was reading through Serialization and Externalization in Java.

Individually I was able to use both the interfaces and was able to serialize and deserialize an object.

But as in Java, a class can implement multiple interface. I implemented both the interface in single class.

Now during runtime, how I can choose which serialization mechanism to choose?

I was wondering why this question has not been asked before! 
Is the question too lame?

**Edit:** My question is different from the question already asked on the forum.

Comment: Interface `Externalizable's`  Superinterface is  `Serializable`.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html

Comment: My question is different from the links you guys have given. Have you ever tried implementing both interface in single class??

Comment: No, your question is identical. If you implement `Externalizable` you are automatically implementing `Serializable` since the former inherits from the latter.

Comment: You can't choose. `Externalizable` wins if present.